# download a file when link clicked in angular 9?

Tags: file, angular9

I'm new to angular.I'm using primeng `upload` to upload files. after uploading I'm showing it as links in my page by looping through it.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let document of searchVideoConsultation.TmpDocument">
          <div class="ui-g form-group">
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-9">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)"
                (click)="onClick($event, searchVideoConsultation)">{{document.Document?.Name}}</a>
            </div>
      </div>
</ng-container>
```

I want to download an uploaded file when clicking on the link.

How can I achieve this?